# jQuery causes elements disappear

Tags: jquery, opencart

I am redesigning an Opencart shop and I have an unexpected problem caused by jQuery.

I must say that unfortunately I don't have any knowledge about jQuery . I am a graphical designer who just have to deal with this problem, so I can't really identify what causes it.

So this is for example one of the pages : http://refletnature.com/tout-sur-la-rose-damascena that has some issue : when you click on the image it fades out and the content below it disappears. The same happens in other part of the website and also here : http://refletnature.com/promotions when you add a product to the cart.

When jQuery is disabled this problem does not exist. 
If anyone can help me with this mystery, I would be more than happy!

Comment: Saying "when I remove *all program code* the problem vanishes" is not as helpful as you might think. :) Turning off jQuery turns off any number of features on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this piece of code in your `common.js` file. I have reproduced just the minimum to see the problem in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9p42kcj/

```
$('.success img, .warning img, .attention img, .information img').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

It basically listens for a `click` event on any image under the div with `class="information"` (or `warning` or `success` or `attention`) and hides everything from the parent of the image on down (quite a lot) then removes the image clicked.

The reason you have a problem is that a class of `information` is used for information panels that you can click to close, as well as a style on the div around your images.

**Solution:**

**Change the class on your `<div class="information">` in the page, and any CSS styles that use .information, to use a different class name.**

In this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9p42kcj/1/ I simply renamed the class from `information` to `info` and the click behavior will stop.

---

*Previous notes below:*

For now comment out those lines (until you figure out what you want to happen:

```
//$('.success img, .warning img, .attention img, .information img').live('click', function() {
//  $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() {
//      $(this).remove();
//  });
//});
```

One solution is to make sure the image is within another DIV, which will control what is removed,  but the actual desired aim of clicking the images is not apparent from the website. **Why should any of it disappear when you click an image?**

*At a guess those divs should not have `information` as one of their classes.* I think that click effect may be for popup notices/warnings/information etc.

Comment: Well, I don't want any content to disappear. At some pages there are images that are links, and other times the user may click randomly on the images - I want to keep all the content on the page in all the cases.

Comment: @Елена Буланова: You need to either remove `,.information img` from the selector, or change your class name to something else. It is the use of the class "information" on the large pictures that has broken your website. I will update my answer based on your comments.

Comment: You just solved my problem, thank you so much! I would buy you a beer if you were in my office ;)

Comment: @Елена Буланова: You are welcome (and you could always move your office closer) :)